# Getting a for loop working

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to split apart the system path variable with batch.
This is what I have:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set npath=%path%
set i=0
echo %npath% > temp
for /f "delims=;" %%a in (temp) do (
    echo [!i!]: %%a
    set /a i=!i!+1
)
```

When it runs, however, it only runs the loop a single time. Instead of my expected output, a list of the directories in PATH, it just outputs a single one:

[image: stupid lazy batch]

What's happening? Am I doing something wrong? I've tried using path as a string, I've tried changing the number of tokens, I've tried like everything. Do I just not understand how for loops work in batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to iterate the items in the path with plain FOR loop (and you need to set quotes to prevent space collisions):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "_path="!path:;=" "!""
rem echo %_path%
set i=0
for %%a in (%_path%) do (
    echo [!i!]: %%~a
    set /a i=!i!+1
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? I don't understand 1) the first `set` line 2) the point of the tilde in `%%~a`

Comment: Woah, printing out the `_path` variable, it looks like you did some kind of fancy find and replace. How?!?! In such short code!!

Comment: @Aarilight the set line replaces `;` with `" ; "` and puts two additional quotes on both sides of the string. `%%~a` removes the quotes around a string

Comment: Ooooh, I understand it now. Man, that's so much cleaner than what I was trying to do. Thank you so much.